# How can I share data between components through a service?

Tags: angular11

I am having trouble sharing information between components. What I am trying to do is, show in the `home.component.html` data that is generated in the `about.component.ts`.
The operation would be:
By means of a `button` in the `home.component.html`, a function in the `home.component.ts` is called, this function calls a function of the `about-service.ts`, which collects the data from the `about.component.html` that obtains the `about.component.ts` data.

This is my `home.component.html`:

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="goToAbout()">
     <mat-icon svgIcon="logoBN"></mat-icon>
      Acerca
</button>
```

This is my `home.component.ts`:

```
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';

 export class HomeComponent {
 public aboutInfo: AboutService;

 goToAbout() {
      .subscribe(emitData =>
 }
```

}

From the `goToAbout()` function of the `home.component.ts` I need to get the data from the `aboutBuild()` function of the `about.component.ts`:

This is my `about.component.ts`:

```
import { AboutService } from '';
    export class AboutComponent {
        ngOnInit() {
          }

        aboutBuild() {
              ......code.........
        }
    }
```

This is my `about.component.html`:

```
<header class="title-color" fxFlex>Build Info</header>
```

I have created a function in the service to try to communicate both components.

`about-service.ts`:

```
observer = new Subject();

public subscriber$ = this.observer.asObservable();

emitData(aboutBuild) {
    this.observer.next(aboutBuild);
}
```

But I can't access the `aboutBuild()` function of the `about.component.ts`, what do I need to include in the `service` to communicate the two components?

Comment: NgOnInit is a lifecycle hook of angular not a just function. You can't do that... First you need to make sure why you want to call one function of a component in another. Doing this will increase the coupling between classes which is not a good idea. Its always preferred to create services for such cases and inject it in your classes. Check angular.io for how to do communication between components the right way.

Comment: The code belongs to the second component (about), but I also need to call it from home. Do you know how to do it in this case? I am testing but cannot access.

Comment: It can be done via service only

Comment: For more information for this please check this https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I cannot replicate the case because it is for parents and children who share the same service. I have two independent components, from one I need to access the function of another.

Comment: Any 2 independent components can use a common service even if they are not parent and child. Both will import that same service. One will publish an event to trigger some operation, the other component will subscribe to that event and upon the trigger it will call its function

Comment: In this way the dependencies would be from components to service and not from component to component. This way both the components will still be independent. Its like introducing a middle ware in between them.

Comment: Ok I'm working on it, I have changed the home function to point to the service, now in the service I have added an observable to the about ngOnInit function. (I put the new code in the question)

Comment: I would say it again NgOnInit is a lifecycle hook and should not be used as normal function. Please create a separate new function in the component and use it.

Comment: I have created the ``buildInfo()`` function outside of the ngOnInit, but I don't know how to complete the service, at the moment I have updated what I have

Comment: Here please follow this article on component communication. The point no. 3 here explains the service method which I'm trying to explain. 
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-component-communication

Comment: I understand that from the ``aboutBuild()`` function of the ``about.component.ts`` I have to call the ``emitData()`` of the ``about-service.ts``, and from the ``goToAbout()`` function of the ``home.component.ts`` I have to subscribe to ``emitData()`` of the ``about-service .ts``? But how do I send the data from the ``about.component.ts`` to the ``about-service.ts``?

Comment: During emitting the event you can pass an object or array of objects

Comment: Ok is what I'm trying to do but I can't get it to work and it doesn't show anything. I'm putting logs but it does not enter the about.component.ts function. I'm pretty stuck in this part I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Update the post with your latest code of all 3 classes. 2 component and 1 service. I'll check.

Comment: Or maybe if u can put ur code in stackblitz then I can see and review

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-l5mtng?file=src%2Fui%2Fabout%2Fabout.compoent.html, What I need is to show the about.component.html by clicking on the build button of the home.component.html

Comment: Why there is no routing?

Comment: I expect home page (/home) to have a button "build" which route me to about page (/about)

Comment: For this I need to add routings in my project

Comment: It wouldn't let me create it in the stackblitz, but the code right now is as I have it in the question. I'll update it in the stackblitz to see if it lets me. Could you tell me how to send the information from ``about.component.ts`` to ``about-service.ts`` and from ``about-service.ts`` to ``home.component.ts``? It is being very difficult for me

Comment: Let me make an answer wait

Answer (score 0):

The AboutService is fine you have one public subscriber and a function to trigger event.

Your goToAbout() in `home.component.ts` :

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(public aboutService: AboutService) {}
   
  goToAbout() {
     let data = {key: 'value'};
     this.aboutService.emitData(data);
  }
}
```

Then your `about.component.ts`:

```
export class AboutComponent {
   constructor(public aboutService: AboutService) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.aboutService.subscriber$.subscribe(data => {
             this.aboutBuild(data);
        });
    }

    aboutBuild(data) {
          console.log(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add it in stackblitz to see how it works? Because I can't get the components to communicate

Comment: Ok I already fixed it without using the ``service``, if not by calling directly the ``ngOnInit`` of the ``aboutComponent``